# Instrumentation.onError() doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, instrumentation

I have some instrumentation code that works nicely. I have added it in the manifest and its called from the main activity of my app.

The only glitch is that the `onException` method that I have overriden doesn't seem to be called ever. I have to use hacks like `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` to catch those exceptions.

Moreover, I would have returned `false` in `onException()` so that after I collect the useful information, the application would crash as expected. But this doesn't seem to work with `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`

I feel that this code is broken and need to addressed by the android developers. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm having similar problems.